# rdply and .id argument - NULL doesn't work as described

Tags: r, plyr

The docs for `rdply` in the `plyr` package say this about the `.id` argument:

```
 .id: name of the index column. Pass ‘NULL’ to avoid creation of
      the index column. For compatibility, omit this argument or
      pass ‘NA’ to avoid converting the index column to a factor;
      in this case, ‘".n"’ is used as colum name..
```

Unfortunately the described behavior does not seem to work when I pass NULL. Consider:

```
>rdply(20, mean(runif(20)))
   .n           V1
1   1 0.4202275122
2   2 0.5140590765
3   3 0.4201277295
4   4 0.4082553896
...
```

Now, I try to get rid of the index column:

```
> rdply(20, mean(runif(20)),.id=NULL)
Error in if (!is.na(.id)) names(labels) <- .id :
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(.id) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Question: How do I use the .id argument to avoid creation of the index column, as described in the documentation?

Comment: It's a bug. You could report at http://github.com/hadley/plyr. Check source code for `rdply` (and `ldply`), error is caused by `if (is.na(.id))`. `is.na(NULL)` returns `logical(0)` which is not handled by `if`.

Comment: BTW: What is the question?

Comment: You can remove it with mutate afterwards: `mutate(rdply(20,mean(rnorm(20))),.n=NULL)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait until this will be fixed or use name of existing column as `.id` :

```
> rdply(20, mean(runif(20)), .id="V1")
       V1
1  0.4804
2  0.6339
3  0.5460
4  0.4473
5  0.4639
6  0.4759
```

Comment: Decent enough solution. It does look like this is a bug